# NSMutableArray property is not working in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a view controller that has a tableView embedded inside of it. I have the following code.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* eventArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.eventTableView.delegate = self;
    self.eventTableView.dataSource = self;

     if (!self.eventArray){
        self.eventArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }

    ...

    for(NSDictionary* dict in responseObject){

            [self.eventArray addObject:[[Event alloc] initWithEventName:[dict valueForKey:@"Name"]eventDescription:[dict valueForKey:@"Description"]]];
        }

    [self.eventTableView reloadData];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    for(Event* event in self.eventArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"Event Name in numberofRows: [%@]", [event eventName]);
    }
    return [self.eventArray count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"EventCell";

    EventTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    Event* eventForCell = (Event*)[self.eventArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSLog(@"eventArraySize [%lu]", [self.eventArray count]);

    for(Event* event in self.eventArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"Event Name: [%@]", [event eventName]);
    }


    [cell.eventNameLabel setText: [eventForCell eventName]];
    return cell;
}
```

As the code is running through I see that the objects are added into the eventArray successfully, and the log loop that I print in numberOfRowsInSection prints the following

```
Event Name in numberofRows: [Worship Rehearsal]
Event Name in numberofRows: [Worship Rehearsal]
Event Name in numberofRows: [Worship Rehearsal]
```

The same loop in the cellForRowAtIndexPath prints out the following

```
eventArraySize [3]
Event Name: [(null)]
Event Name: [(null)]
Event Name: [(null)]
```

I have tried this with other properties and I am able to access them correctly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Everything is good, your event name is nil

Comment: Can you post the rest of the view controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, thanks for the help. The issue was in my Event Object, The properties were set as weak instead of strong references. Once I changed them to:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *eventName;
```

The objects started working as expected. The array itself was working correctly, but the fields inside of my Event objects were being released.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your event is nil. It's because there is a problem when you initialize the array.

This is wrong`[dict valueForKey:@"Name"]`

Use this `[dict objectForKey:@"Name"]`

Or simply `dict[@"Name"]`

Answer (score 0):

To print events name for each cell can you try using this code ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"EventCell";

    EventTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    Event* eventForCell = (Event*)[self.eventArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSLog(@"eventArraySize [%lu]", [self.eventArray count]);

    //for(Event* event in self.eventArray)
    //{
    //   NSLog(@"Event Name: [%@]", [event eventName]);
    //}
    //Commenting above code

    NSLog(@"Event Name: [%@]", [eventForCell eventName]);

    [cell.eventNameLabel setText: [eventForCell eventName]];
    return cell;
}
```